# What is <x></x> and <y></y>? Is there anyone knowing this?

Tags: xml, annotations, data-annotations, object-detection

I used VATIC video annotation tool (http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~vondrick/vatic/)
for the first time for labeling object in a video.

I conducted the following procedure.

1.Install Docker

2.Create Container
`sudo docker run -it -p 8111:80 -v $PWD/data:/root/vatic/data npsvisionlab/vatic-docker`

3.Open browser
`localhost:8111/directory`

4.Label some object at browser

5.Output file
By pushing the button `Output Labels`, `output.xml` file was automatically created.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztcjr.png)

After that, I checked the output file `output.xml`. 
However, I couldn't understand what does`<x></x>` and `<y></y>` denotes in the output file.

Some lines in the `output.xml` are here.

`<object><name>potB</name><moving>true</moving><action/><verified>0</verified><id>2</id><createdFrame>85</createdFrame><startFrame>85</startFrame><endFrame>2641</endFrame>
<polygon><t>85</t><pt><x>239</x><y>309</y><l>1</l></pt><pt><x>239</x><y>403</y><l>1</l></pt><pt><x>394</x><y>403</y><l>1</l></pt><pt><x>394</x><y>309</y><l>1</l></pt></polygon>
<polygon><t>86</t><pt><x>238</x><y>303</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>238</x><y>400</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>392</x><y>400</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>392</x><y>303</y><l>0</l></pt></polygon>
<polygon><t>87</t><pt><x>237</x><y>297</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>237</x><y>398</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>391</x><y>398</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>391</x><y>297</y><l>0</l></pt></polygon>`
.
.
.
.
`<polygon><t>2639</t><pt><x>325</x><y>119</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>325</x><y>243</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>519</x><y>243</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>519</x><y>119</y><l>0</l></pt></polygon>
<polygon><t>2640</t><pt><x>324</x><y>119</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>324</x><y>243</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>519</x><y>243</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>519</x><y>119</y><l>0</l></pt></polygon>
<polygon><t>2641</t><pt><x>324</x><y>119</y><l>1</l></pt><pt><x>324</x><y>243</y><l>1</l></pt><pt><x>520</x><y>243</y><l>1</l></pt><pt><x>520</x><y>119</y><l>1</l></pt></polygon>
</object>`

At present, I just know one of the `<polygon></polygon>` denotes one boundary box information.
And `<t></t>` is flame number.

There are 4 sets of `<x></x>` and `<y></y>` in a `<polygon></polygon>`.

Again, my question is here.
What does those `<x></x>` and `<y></y>` denotes respectively?
Where are the `x_min` `y_min` `x_max` `y_max`?

And if you know,
What is the definition of `x_min` `y_min` `x_max` `y_max`?

Comment: You are basically asking about how to use some software that you have downloaded.  That is off-topic.  But here is a hint: look at the source code.  Specifically at "cli.py" in the github repo at https://github.com/cvondrick/vatic.  This "defines" how the XML is produced and the rest of the code "defines" what it means.

Comment: Hint 2: the `<x>` and `<y>` XML elements define the x and y coordinates of points which are the vertices of a polygon.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for answering my question!  I got some information at Github that you suggested to me and almost understand that. There is the rule ①<x>`x_min`</x><y>`y_min`</y>, ②<x>`x_min`</x><y>`y_max`</y>, ③<x>`x_max`</x><y>`y_max`</y>, ④<x>`x_max`</x><y>`y_max`</y> in the order left to right.